# android studio debug on device makes 2 application icon on application list

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio (v1.0). I've created a project on it and when I debug or run project from android studio into my Galaxy Nexus phone, I see 2 application icon on application list. And when I uninstall one of them another one also removes. The package name of both are the same.
Is this normal? Maybe I forgot to do some settings.
My `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aliaa.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

Does Anyone have same experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml file and inspect `<activity>` entries. Anything with `intent filter` like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

will be listed by Launcher as entry point. You usually need one entry point per app.